# Identify point inside a polygon (inclusive of point lying on boundaries and edges)

Tags: javascript, turfjs

I am using turf.js to find a point inside a polygon and i found the problem persisting for several use cases one of such use case is as below below mentioned use case (i.e. for point (X=32.8,Y=40). I have also plotted the image for reference for which **turf.booleanPointInPolygon** is showing false.
[Image of Graph plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IySEQ.png)

```
var turf = require("@turf/turf");

var pt = turf.point([32.8,40]);
var poly = turf.polygon([[

 [ 7.2  ,           160.0],
[38.3,              30.0],
[65.1   ,           30.0],
[62.3   ,           96.0],
[18.4   ,           325.0],
[7.6    ,           380.0],
[7.5    ,           307.0],
[7.4    ,           234.0],
[7.2    ,           160.0]

]]);

var bool = turf.booleanPointInPolygon(pt, poly, {ignoreBoundary: false});
//bool = false, even though the point is inside the polygon
```

failed to recognize a point within the polygon, this is a glitch from turf.js. 
How to report to turf.js. Anyone please help in fixing this.

Comment: can you explain how it is wrong ? I have also attached an image where the point is lying exactly inside the polygon and **turf.booleanPointInPolygon** is showing false. Please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your point is not inside the polygon. There is no bug in turf.js. You probably been tricked because your plotted graph is completely wrong.

Here it is how your polygon should look likes on a graph. You see that your point (J) is clearly outside:

[image]

Comment: Hey can you please tell me what is the tool you are using for plotting? Also i am plotting it as a log graph and not a simple XvsY graph

Comment: Got it. Turf is making use of the typical XvsY scatter plot but my representation is rendered as a log graph. Can you please suggest any solution for this. I cant find any suitable approach for finding a point within a polygon (now that i have to check for a polgon represented in log scale)

Comment: Hi I found a solution. I converted the cartesian x-axis array, y-axis array and the point to be found to log scale using Math.log(x) in javascript before feeding to turf.js for creating polygon and the point to be found. It is rendering correctly now. The major flaw was that i plotted my coordinates in log scale and was seeking turfs solution by passing cartesian data (which i converted to log scale before sending to turf)

Answer (score 2):

I converted the cartesian x-axis array, y-axis array and the point to be found to log scale using `Math.log(x)` in javascript before feeding to turf.js for creating polygon and the point to be found within it. It is rendering correctly now. The major flaw was that i plotted my coordinates in log scale and was seeking turfs solution by passing cartesian data (which i converted to log scale before sending to turf)